# Difference between "requests in top-level queue" and "requests in queue" in Phusion Passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I have a setup running nginx and phusion passenger version 4.0.37

Does anyone know what the difference is between "Requests in top-level queue" and "Requests in queue" when running `sudo passenger-status`? In what cases would these numbers diverge? I am seeing cases where "Requests in queue" gets large (because of socket or networking problems blocking a thread), but "Requests in top-level queue" always stays at 0, which suggests to me that perhaps there are application-specific queues and a separate concept of a top-level queue. But then I don't understand in what cases a top-level queue comes into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phusion Passenger's internal state consists of a list of Groups (representing applications), each which consist of a list of Processes (representing application processes). When spawning the first process for an application, Phusion Passenger has to create and initialize a Group data structure, run hooks, etc. Since this involves reading from disk and running processes, it can potentially take an arbitrary amount of time. During that time, said request, and any new requests targeted at that application, are put in the top-level queue until the Group is done initializing.

Each Group has its own queue. As soon as the Group is initialized, relevant requests from the top-level queue are moved to the Group-local queue.

This is the reason why the top-level queue is usually empty.

The sum of the values of all Group-local queues, plus the value of the top-level queue, is the total number of requests that are queued. In general, if they are non-zero for a long time then that's bad.